# Replace string in int

Tags: vuejs2

I have a simple question but I don't know how to solve it.
This is my code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.values.length; i++) {
  this.affinityZone.push({
    'text': response.data.values[i].name,
    **'value': response.data.values[i].id**
  })
}
```

The `'value'` is a string now. So how can my frontend read it as integer.
I tried: `'value': parseInt == response.data.values[i].id` and `'value': parseInt.response.data.values[i].id`.

Comment: `parseInt(response.data.values[i].id, 10)`.

Comment: thank you, but I also tried this and it didn't work

Comment: You say *"The 'value' is a string now."* what is its contents? What string is it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're trying to do something like this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.values.length; i++) {
  this.affinityZone.push({
    text: response.data.values[i].name,
    value: parseInt(response.data.values[i].id, 10)
  })
}
```

Comment: What type is `response.data.values[i].id`? Can you provide an example of data in that `values` array?

Comment: unknown value "1" for enum api.AffinityValues

Comment: Looks like `affinityZone` doesn't accept integers. What's `api.AffinityValues`? Does it return anything?

Comment: yes, it does return values....
enum AffinityValues {
  UNDEFINED_AFFINITY = 0;
  RED = 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
'value': Number.parseInt(response.data.values[i].id)
```

I should insert Number to parseInt.

Thank you all.